# What is the swift 2 equivalent to the swift 3 "string contains" function? by npn.dev

Tags: string, swift2, xcode7

*Hello,
I would like to know what is the equivalent of Swift 3*

> mySong.contains

*for Swift 2 on Xcode 7 (because I want to create an application for iPhone 4). Excuse me for my english because I am french... and google translation help me*

**My code :**

```
func gettingSongName(){

    let folderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!)

    do{

        let songPath = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

        for song in songPath{

            var mySong = song.absoluteString

            if mySong.contains(".mp3") { // Value of type 'String' has no member 'contains'

                let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/") // Value of type 'String' has no member 'components'
                mySong = findString[findString.count-1]
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ") // Value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurences'
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "e%CC%81", with: "é") // Value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurences'
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "e%CC%82", with: "ê") // Value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurences'
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: "") // Value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurences'
                songs.append(mySong)
                print(mySong)

            }

        }

        myTableView.reloadData()

    }catch{

    }

}
```

*thank you in advance,*
**npn.dev**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `range string` method in swift 2 and Xcode 7.3.1

```
let string = "This is only a test"

if string.rangeOfString("only") != nil {
 print("yes")
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I dont't understand @Pal Singh Anand

Comment: what you don't understand bro?

Comment: You just replace if mySong.contains(".mp3") to if mySong.rangeOfString(".mp3") != nil